# PrincipalPermissionAttribute demand same role from multiple domains

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-authentication, principalpermission

### Setup

My WCF webservice runs on IIS 8.0 on Windows Server 2012 in an evironment with multiple domains:

- SERVER
- CLIENT-OLD
- CLIENT-NEW

the application pool runs using a service account in the `SERVER` domain (lets say `SEVER\WsSvc01`).

My WCF webservice uses a `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` like this:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "grp_WsUsers")]
public string Echo(string message)
{
    return string.Format("{0:o}: {1}", DateTime.Now, message);
}
```

there is a `grp_WsUsers` active directory group in both client domains:

- CLIENT-OLD\grp_WsUsers
- CLIENT-NEW\grp_WsUsers

### Problem

Users from the `CLIENT-OLD` domain that are members of the `CLIENT-OLD\grp_WsUsers` **can** access the service users from the `CLIENT-NEW` domain **can't**

### Workaround

If I include both groups explicitly all users can access the service

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "CLIENT-OLD\\grp_WsUsers")]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "CLIENT-NEW\\grp_WsUsers")]
public string Echo(string message)
{
    return string.Format("{0:o}: {1}", DateTime.Now, message);
}
```

### Question

What is happening here? If I have to specify the groups explicitly why does it work at all in the first place? How can I tack down the differences between the two groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out:

the permission check invoked by the `PricipalPermissionAttribute` simply looks for the **first** group with the name in any domain it comes across **and stops after that** even if the current user does not have the group.

So in my case the the implementation looked for the group in the `CLIENT-OLD` domain first and since a group with the name in question exists there checks all users for this specific group (groups SID I assume).